# Date pattern in java regex

Tags: java, regex

I make one function Datepattern which contain array list and am adding date pattern regex 
My code is as below

private ArrayList getDatePatterns() {
        ArrayList alDate = new ArrayList();

```
    //Thursday, the 7th December, 2006.00
    alDate.add("\\b(?i)(monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday)[ ]*[,][ ]*(the)[ ]*[0-9]+(st|th|rd|nd)?[ ]*(Jan[.]?|January|Feb[.]?|February|Mar[.]?|March|Apr[.]?|April|May|Jun[.]?|June|Jul[.]?|July|Aug[.]?|August|Sep[t]?[.]?|September|Oct[.]?|October|Nov[.]?|November|Dec[.]?|December)[ ]*[,][ ]*[0-9]+\\b");


    //Examples: 24th July to 3rd August, 2007  24 July to 3 August, 2007  
    alDate.add("\\b(?i)(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(st|th|rd|nd)?([ ])?(Jan[.]?|January|Feb[.]?|February|Mar[.]?|March|Apr[.]?|April|May|Jun[.]?|June|Jul[.]?|July|Aug[.]?|August|Sep[t]?[.]?|September|Oct[.]?|October|Nov[.]?|November|Dec[.]?|December)[ ]?(to)([ ])?(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(st|th|rd|nd)?([ ])?(Jan[.]?|January|Feb[.]?|February|Mar[.]?|March|Apr[.]?|April|May|Jun[.]?|June|Jul[.]?|July|Aug[.]?|August|Sep[t]?[.]?|September|Oct[.]?|October|Nov[.]?|November|Dec[.]?|December)[ ]*[\\,]?([ ])*([0-9]+)?\\b");

  //Examples: 1.4.94-to-25.1.95 
   // alDate.add("\\b(?i)[0-9]+[ ]*[.][ ]*[0-9]+[ ]*[.][ ]*[0-9]+[ ]*[.][ ]*(to)[ ]*[0-9]+[ ]*[.][ ]*[0-9]+[ ]*[.][ ]*[0-9]+\\b");

    //Examples: 9th & 12th August,   9th and 12th August, 2008 9th to 12th August, 2008 9th/12th August, 2008 9th-12th August, 2008
  ////////  alDate.add("\\b(?i)(?:(from)?([ ])?0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[ ]*(st|th|rd|nd)?([ ])?(and|to|\\/|[\\-]|&)([ ])?(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[ ]*(st|th|rd|nd)?([ ])?(of)?([ ])?(Jan[.]?|January|Feb[.]?|February|Mar[.]?|March|Apr[.]?|April|May|Jun[.]?|June|Jul[.]?|July|Aug[.]?|August|Sep[t]?[.]?|September|Oct[.]?|October|Nov[.]?|November|Dec[.]?|December)[ ]*[\\,]*([ ])?([0-9]+)?\\b");

    //Example : 28th July 28 July 24 July 2007 24-July-2007 24th July, 2007 24 July, 2007 24th day of July, 2007  21st of May, 2008


    alDate.add("\\b(?i)(Letter No[.]?[ |-])?(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([\\-]|[ ])?(st|th|rd|nd)?([ ])?(day[ ]of[ ])?(of[ ])?(Jan[.]?|January|Feb[.]?|February|Mar[.]?|March|Apr[.]?|April|May|Jun[.]?|June|Jul[.]?|July|Aug[.]?|August|Sep[t]?[.]?|September|Oct[.]?|October|Nov[.]?|November|Dec[.]?|December)([ ]?[\\,]?([\\-]|[ ])?([0-9]+))\\b");

    //Example :  August 24,  07; November 26-30, 2007
    alDate.add("\\b(?i)(?:Jan[.]?|January|Feb[.]?|February|Mar[.]?|March|Apr[.]?|April|May|Jun[.]?|June|Jul[.]?|July|Aug[.]?|August|Sep[.]?|Sept[.]?|September|Oct[.]?|October|Nov[.]?|November|Dec[.]?|December)[ ]?((0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[ ]?[-][ ]?)?(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([ ])?[\\,]([ ])?([0-9]+)?\\b");

    //June 08 and June 2008; May'08 and June'08
    alDate.add("\\b(?i)(?:Jan[.]?|January|Feb[.]?|February|Mar[.]?|March|Apr[.]?|April|May|Jun[.]?|June|Jul[.]?|July|Aug[.]?|August|Sep[.]?|Sept[.]?|September|Oct[.]?|October|Nov[.]?|November|Dec[.]?|December)[ ]?([\\,\\'])?([ ])?([0-9]+)?[ ]*(and)[ ]*(?:Jan[.]?|January|Feb[.]?|February|Mar[.]?|March|Apr[.]?|April|May|Jun[.]?|June|Jul[.]?|July|Aug[.]?|August|Sep[.]?|Sept[.]?|September|Oct[.]?|October|Nov[.]?|November|Dec[.]?|December)[ ]?([\\,\\'])?([ ])?([0-9]+)?\\b");
    //Example : March, 2009;  March 2009; June-April, 2008
    alDate.add("\\b(?i)((?:Jan[.]?|January|Feb[.]?|February|Mar[.]?|March|Apr[.]?|April|May|Jun[.]?|June|Jul[.]?|July|Aug[.]?|August|Sep[.]?|Sept[.]?|September|Oct[.]?|October|Nov[.]?|November|Dec[.]?|December)[ ]?[-][ ]?)?(?:Jan[.]?|January|Feb[.]?|February|Mar[.]?|March|Apr[.]?|April|May|Jun[.]?|June|Jul[.]?|July|Aug[.]?|August|Sep[.]?|Sept[.]?|September|Oct[.]?|October|Nov[.]?|November|Dec[.]?|December)[ ]?([\\,])?([ ])?[0-9]+\\b");              

    //Examples: from dd-mm-yy to    dd-mm-yy  dd/mm/yy ,  dd.mm.yy   etc
  //  alDate.add("\\b(?i)(i[.]e[.]|viz[.]|means)\\s(from[ ])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([\\.]|[\\-]|[ \\/])+(?:0?[1-9]|1[0|1|2])([\\.]|[\\-]|[ \\/])+[0-9]+([ ]to[ ])(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([\\.]|[\\-]|[ \\/])+(?:0?[1-9]|1[0|1|2])([\\.]|[\\-]|[ \\/])+[0-9]+\\b");
  //  alDate.add("\\b(?i)(from[ ])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([\\.]|[\\-]|[ \\/])+(?:0?[1-9]|1[0|1|2])([\\.]|[\\-]|[ \\/])+[0-9]+([ ]to[ ])(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([\\.]|[\\-]|[ \\/])+(?:0?[1-9]|1[0|1|2])([\\.]|[\\-]|[ \\/])+[0-9]+\\b");

    // 28th Feburary
    alDate.add("\\b(?i)(the)?[ ]*[0-9]+(st|th|rd|nd)?[ ]*(Jan[.]?|January|February|Feb[.]?|Mar[.]?|March|Apr[.]?|April|May|Jun[.]?|June|Jul[.]?|July|Aug[.]?|August|Sep[t]?[.]?|September|Oct[.]?|October|Nov[.]?|November|Dec[.]?|December)");

    //Examples: dd-mm-yy    , dd/mm/yy ,  dd.mm.yy   etc
    alDate.add("\\b(?i)(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([\\.]|[\\-]|[ \\/])+(?:0?[1-9]|1[0|1|2])([\\.]|[\\-]|[ \\/])+[0-9]+\\b");

    //2002-2003
    //alDate.add("\\b([0-9]+[\\-][0-9]+)\\b");
    return alDate;
}
```

Instead of this i Want one single regex that satisfies all the above conditions.In comment for more understanding I mentioned the date pattern that regex follows.
 any one help me I want to write one single regex for date pattern instead of this large code.
I want to reduce the code.
Thank u

Comment: I don't think you can get a simple regexp for all cases. Only by doing one big OR, which will be less readable than what you have

Answer (score 3):

Don't use RegEx for date parsing, use `SimpleDateFormat`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question is very vague about what you want to achieve with your code. To me it sounds like you want to parse date strings in different formats and maybe convert them to a `Date` object as in [`DateFormat.parse(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29).

**Edit**: I'm almost completely sure, regular expressions aren't the right tool for the task your code is trying to perform, but that you don't want to reveal for some reason. I'm quite sure, you are trying to re-implement a solution to a common and delicate problem with a shitload of pitfalls especially concerning internationalisation. Usually these can be solved with a small set of library functions which preserve the programmer (you), the future maintainer of this mess, and the (prospecting) users of the application from dealing with the aforementioned problems and their consequences.

In any way, glueing the REs together will make it even less readable/maintainable.

Comment: Sir instead of adding different date format that i mentioned in comment .i want only one regex that follow all pattern so that i that i need not to be add again and again diferent pattern .only one regex will do this

Comment: But what is the purpose? Check the format? Parse the date? What will be the source?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj Can I write more simple regex than this like for 1st alDate.add("\\b(?i)(monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday)[ ]*[,][ ]*(the)[ ]*[0-9]+(st|th|rd|nd)?[ ]*(Jan[.]?|January|Feb[.]?|February|Mar[.]?|March|Apr[.]?|April|May|Jun[.]?|June|Jul[.]?|July|Aug[.]?|August|Sep[t]?[.]?|September|Oct[.]?|October|Nov[.]?|November|Dec[.]?|December)[ ]*[,][ ]*[0-9]+\\b");

Can i make it simple small regex???

Comment: Tell us the purpose of the code you're trying to create. Then you'll get better answers.